# Why does node.js look for error as the first parameter in a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following simple code.. however the "data" variable doesn't return the contents of input.txt.

```
var fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile('input.txt', function (data) {
     console.log(data.toString());
});

console.log("Program Ended");
```

The code below works because node.js reads the first parameter, err, and the input.txt contents come from the 2nd parameter

```
var fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile('input.txt', function (err, data) {
   if (err) return console.error(err);
   console.log(data.toString());
});

console.log("Program Ended");
```

Is this just a node.js thing to look for the error in the first parameter? What if I did not want to check for an error in the callback function?

Comment: *"What if I did not want to check for an error in the callback function?"* You simply ignore that parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's convention to pass error as the first parameter to a callback function. It's first to prevent it from being ignored. You don't have to check it, of course, but if there is an error it's likely that your `data` is bad or meaningless anyway.

The reason that `fs.readFile('input.txt', function (data) {` doesn't work is that the error is passed into your `data` variable, since it is the first parameter. What you actually name the parameters doesn't matter, the parameter order is decided by `fs.readFile`.

Comment: I see, it's a convention. So, this is for all node.js callback functions?

Comment: @SwolleyBible: Pretty much. But the corresponding documentation will tell you.

Comment: @SwolleyBible It's just a convention, but it's used almost everywhere for good reason. In your case, whoever wrote `fs.readFile` decided that the first callback parameter was the error. There is no reason that you couldn't write a function that takes a callback with a different parameter order, but it would be confusing and inconsistent if you did.